# PLSQL Trigger Equality check

Tags: triggers

i need a Trigger for my project at university which checks a equality before inserting on a table. That means on table costumer is a variable which is called username and before inserting a new username it should check if the username exists. I dont know how exactly i should do this.

Comment: are you using oracle db? if so, try using  `EXISTS ` condition before insert.

Comment: just using normal db for our project. 
It should look like this i think : 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BENUTZERNAME
BEFORE INSERT ON KUNDE. 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    Benutzername KUNDE.Benutzername;
BEGIN
if (:new.Benutzername <> :old.Benutzername)
    Then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,"Existiert bereits");
else 

*keep inserting the new name* 

  NULL;
END;

so if the new username is equal to one username in the table it should cause a application error and else it should keep inserting

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BENUTZERNAME
BEFORE INSERT ON KUNDE. 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    Benutzername KUNDE.Benutzername;
BEGIN
if (:new.Benutzername <> :old.Benutzername)
    Then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,"Existiert bereits");
else 

*keep inserting the new name* 

  NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for time being.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER BENUTZERNAME
BEFORE INSERT ON KUNDE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
counter number(10):=0;
BEGIN
select count(1) into counter from KUNDE where userid = :new.Benutzername;
if (counter >0)
Then RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Existiert bereits');
end if;
END;
```

**Triggers are bad way of doing this. Please try using Unique constraint instead.**